Updating a pdf file already displayed in a QAxContainer.QAxWidget when adding more flowables into the document
I want to update a pdf file that is alerady been displayed into a QAxContainer.QAxWidget when a modification (e.g. adding more flowables) has been taken. I want to achive this because the user is going to be creating a quotation file and maybe he wants to add a new product to it (or maybe delete an existing one, etc), so I want changes to be displayed everytime user clicks on the pdf generator button.
I don't know if there is a better approach to achive this but this is what I am trying:

There is a main window which is for input data and when user click on pdf buttom a second window will show up and display the pdf file

if a modification is requiered the user will make them and then click on pdf buttom (again) and the new pdf file will be displayed showing the new changes (whatever they are)


For exemple purposes this is my code for my main window:
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from window import DisplayWindow
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.lib.units import mm
import sys
import urllib.parse


# in points
TOP_MARGIN = 60 * mm
RIGHT_MARGIN = 20 * mm
LEFT_MARGIN = 20 * mm
BOTTOM_MARGIN = 20 * mm

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(439, 300)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdit)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_2)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdit_2)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.formLayout)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "paragraph1:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "paragraph2:"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "pdf"))

class PDFGenerator:
    def __init__(self, lineEdit, lineEdit_2):
        self.lineEdit = lineEdit
        self.lineEdit_2 = lineEdit_2

    def creating_pdf(self):
        doc = SimpleDocTemplate(
            filename="output_file.pdf",
            pagesize=letter,
            rightMargin=RIGHT_MARGIN,
            leftMargin=LEFT_MARGIN,
            topMargin=TOP_MARGIN,
            bottomMargin=BOTTOM_MARGIN
        )

        flowables = []

        para1 = Paragraph(text=self.lineEdit)
        flowables.append(para1)

        para2 = Paragraph(text=self.lineEdit_2)
        flowables.append(para2)

        doc.build(flowables=flowables)

class PDFWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.generating_pdf_file)

        self.display_window = DisplayWindow()

    def generating_pdf_file(self):
        try:
            doc = PDFGenerator(lineEdit=self.lineEdit.text().strip(), lineEdit_2=self.lineEdit_2.text().strip())
            doc.creating_pdf()

            path = r"C:\Users\isDev\OneDrive\Documents\PythonScripts\urimareApp\temp\output_file.pdf"
            self.uri = "file:" + urllib.parse.quote(path)

            self.display_window.uri = self.uri
            self.display_window.show()

        except:
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = PDFWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

and this is my second window (to display the pdf file):
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(860, 769)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.axWidget = QAxContainer.QAxWidget(Form)
        self.axWidget.setObjectName("axWidget")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.axWidget)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
from PyQt5 import QAxContainer

class DisplayWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, uri=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self._uri = uri

        self.axWidget.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.axWidget.setControl("{8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2}")
        self.axWidget.setFixedSize(840, 715)

    @property
    def uri(self):
        return self._uri
    
    @uri.setter
    def uri(self, uri):
        self._uri = uri

        self.axWidget.dynamicCall("Navigate(const QString&)", self._uri)

This code simulates what I am trying to achive. On the main window there is two lineEdits, when I insert data to the first one and click on pdf buttom it displays the second window with the pdf file (everything's ok) but when I return to the main window and insert data in the second lineEdit (modifying the original pdf file) and click, again, the push buttom; nothing happens!
If I close the second window and repeat the last step it displays it back but there is no pdf file in the QAxContainer.QAxWidget and there is only a black square and also I got this message on the cmd:

QAxBase: Error calling IDispatch member Navigate: Exception thrown by
server
Code       : -2147467259
Source     :
Description:
Help       :
Connect to the exception(int,QString,QString,QString) signal to catch this exception

These are the images that show what I said above:
enter image description here
enter image description here
Maybe I am missing something or doing it in a wrong way. Thanks in advance!
